# Getting the Day of Week from a DateTimePicker

Tags: c#, datepicker, dayofweek

I have a 2d array and if the date selected using the dateTimePicker is a monday I want to set the row index to 1. If the date selected is a tuesday I want to set the row index to 2... I have tried do this using the code below but it doesn't seem to work:

```
       if (dateTimePicker.Value == DateTime.DayOfWeek.Monday)
       r = 1;  
       if (dateTimePicker.Value == DateTime.DayOfWeek.tuesday)
       r = 2;
```

Comment: +1 (offsetting). Nothing wrong with this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Microsoft's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.aspx), `DateTimePicker.Value` is of type `DateTime`.

Take the `DayOfWeek` [property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.dayofweek.aspx) to get the value you're looking for.

Your statement should look like:

```
if ( dateTimePicker.Value.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday )
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

`dateTimePicker.Value` will contain a full `DateTime`. You're comparing that against a constant. Try comparing `dateTimePicker.Value.DayOfWeek` to the `enum` constants.

Answer (score 0):

Using a Cast

```
int r = (int)dateTimePicker1.Value.DayOfWeek;
```

Comment: Please consider describing your answer in at least a few sentences and avoid putting just some code without explanation.